# Pre-flood Rock Monsters? Modern Noah Mythology?

Tags: bible, noah

How did the "Noah" movie decide to include rock monsters depicted as fallen angels? (helping him, nonetheless!)

This is one of many, many biblical deviations the movie makes, but I'm curious **what traditional sources are bastardizing the story so badly**? Or is it just the creativity of modern man gone unrestrained?

Comment: Well, this has absolutely nothing to do with Christianity.  Why someone who claims to be an atheist came up with the existence of rock monsters prior to the flood has no basis in the Bible at all.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about movie production decisions.

Comment: This question *might* be on-topic on [Movies & TV](http://movies.stackexchange.com/), but it's clearly not on topic here, unless you want to change the question to "Does the Bible mention pre-flood rock monsters?" but you seem to already know the answer to that question.

Comment: Dr. Brian Mattson has written a [post about the Noah movie](http://drbrianmattson.com/journal/2014/3/31/sympathy-for-the-devil) that asserts that most of the movie is based on Kabbalah and Gnosticism.

Comment: As @BenMiller mentioned, I was about to say that, considering the Rock Monster idea is quite similar to a golem, a Jewish mysticism creature. Remember, the story was Jewish for 2000 years before there even were Christians, and is still Jewish today. There's another whole world looking at and interpreting it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the producer of the movie said when asked about inaccuracies in the movie "It is entertainment and not a documentary."

Biblical movies, down through their history, have injected some parts for entertainment into their story line. Even the best made Biblical movies, such Charlton Heston's great movie about Moses, included a love triangle involving Joshua that is not a part of the Bible.

It appears that whether wittingly or unwittingly, Hollywood has deviated from known Scripture in increasingly greater ways, that the Stories from the Bible have been altered in the mind of the public.

Whether intentional or not this process has slowly had a negative impact on the public's perception of the veracity of the Bible.

Many devout Christians have attributed this process to Satan, and there may be more truth to that than meets the eye. However, it must be assumed that it was not a conscious effort on the part of the movie makers to distort the perceptions of the Bible but to satisfy the hunger of the public for increasingly exciting entertainment.

That process is not just reserved for Biblical interpretation in movies, but extends to all movies. Beginning back in the 70's with movies, such as where the girl's head spun around on her body, to as you remarked, the depiction of fallen Angels as Rock monsters. Christianity has been rapidly denigrated by Hollywood.

Sadly the depiction of fallen Angels helping Noah, (I have to take your word for that, since I have not seen this movie and never will because I am blind); will give some the idea that Fallen Angels can be good, which is contradictory to the Bible, since the fallen Angels are Satan's demons, and are evil.

One of the first Bible epics, which I still occasionally watch, deviated from the Biblical account of Jesus' crucifixion in that in the Bible Roman soldiers cast lots for Jesus' garments, but in the movie that was not shown.

You can make your own determination as to whether or not this is the work of Satan or not, for myself I can only say that it has had a negative effect on Christianity.

Comment: Who knows - perhaps some future inspired documentation will reference modern movies and their stupidity. I just couldn't wrap my head around rock-monsters! I just couldn't see the rationale, even if they were trying to include "secular" sources. Totally off-the-wall.

Comment: @1Up perhaps, but I'm not sure there will be any future inspired documentation, after all just how much can God put up with!